# Make Point struct understand += operator

Tags: c#, xna

I'd like to know if it is possible to extend `Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Point` struct to work with `+`, `+=`, `-` and `-=` operators. `Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Vector2` has a ton of operators, whereas `Point` has bare minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is only possible to add such an operator overload from the type's definition.  You cannot add an overload from your code to that framework type.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible, but you can add the addition functionality to the `Point` struct like this:

```
public static class PointAritmethicExtensions
    {
        public static Point Add (this Point a, Point b)
        {
            return new Point(a.X + b.X, a.Y + b.Y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot use extension methods for operator overloads.

Comment: I didn't downvote but, you can't use extension methods for operator overloading.  You could add an extension method that adds for you, it just wouldn't be able to express it as `+=` as OP requests.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia If you know that the answer is wrong why *wouldn't* you downvote it?  That's in large part what they're there for.

Comment: @Servy I don't think it's a worthless answer, it's definitely a viable option, just not expressly what OP asked for, which as you answered isn't possible.

Comment: @Servy You can explain what's wrong without downvoting every answer you don't like.

Comment: @pinckerman That's what the feature is there for.  When an answer is wrong, doens't answer the question, has problems, etc. You *should* downvote it.  Otherwise someone might be inclined to think that the content of this answer is correct, dispute the fact that it contains several factual inaccuracies.  Having incorrect answers to questions get upvotes is *harmful*, and downvoting is the means to address that.  Can you explain why what's wrong with downvoting an incorrect answer, or why you *wouldn't* downvote an incorrect answer when you see one?

Comment: @Servy You are right, but this question has already a correct accepted answer with positive upvote, I don't think it's necessary to downvote a not-so-wrong answer which has 0 evaluation.

Comment: @pinckerman The fact that there is an accepted answer doesn't mean that you should treat a wrong answer as if it weren't wrong.  Next, the answer isn't "not so wrong".  It starts out saying, "Yes, it's possible."  It's not actually possible.  It's provably *not* possible.  The statement is 100% wrong.  It then states that extension methods are the means to do it.  That is completely incorrect; extension methods *cannot* be used to overload operators.  Next, it states that you can extend the struct to add new code.  You cannot extend structs.  That is completely wrong and misleading.

Comment: @Servy ; FYI ; Allthough you are right in the sense that you cannot do operator overloading by extension methods, you CAN extend Point using this method. I have done so myself in my latest project.

Comment: @Stig-RuneSkansgård Sure you can, but that's not the question.  The question is about asking how to overload the operators, not how to add methods.  It's an unrelated fact not relevant to the question.  All of the facts that are actually on topic are *completely false*.

Comment: @Servy; While true that the "on-topic" part of his answer was not correct, he still provided a good alternative, which is what makes this site useful; getting help, even though you ask the wrong questions. Also; you still claimed that extending a struct was not possible, which is why I corrected you. Your answer provides the correct answer, but does not help. This is pretty close to being worth a downvote IMHO.

Comment: @Stig-RuneSkansgård But you *can't* extend a struct.  All user defined structs are effectively `sealed` and cannot be extended.  Extension methods don't technically extend a type, they are still static methods outside of the type but can merely be called using a syntax that makes it *appear* as if it's an instance method of that type.  As to solving the problem.  Any old static method can be used to solve the problem, and based on the OP's experience that's not really an issue here.  He was looking for overloaded operators, just just methods.

Comment: @Servy; By "extend" I mean make extension methods. which is demonstrably possible. I am fully aware that they are basicly syntactical sugar, but they still make things a lot easier, and so they are helpfull. As to your "they are still static methods", operator overloading is also just syntactic sugar that performs a method...

Comment: @Stig-RuneSkansgård Even if that's what *you* meant by extend, it's not what the word means.  Extension methods are not technically extending a type, and more importantly to "extend" a type is the *proper* term for creating a new type that is a sub-type of the class being extended.  That's what you *said*, and what the author of this post said, even if that wasn't his intention.  There are tons and tons of random unrelated facts that I could include in any given question, but staying on topic and answering the question needs to take precedence over random side tracks.

Comment: @Servy; No, we wrote extend, as in using extension methods. Which is the correct terminology for using extension methods to extend a class!
YOU are talking about inheritance, which does NOT merely extend a class, but can also alter and/or reuse existing functionality. Sounds like you are confusing the java keyword "extend" with the concept of inheritance.

Comment: @Stig-RuneSkansgård Inheritance is *actually* extending a type.  Extension methods appear to extend a type *but they do not*.  That particular problem is merely a poorly communicated concept, unlike the other problems with the post in which they were flat wrong, despite (apparently) properly communicating it's author's intent.  Not only that, after all of this the author *still* hasn't fixed his post to remove the *blatantly wrong* facts.

Comment: @Servy The term "extension method" is the official terminology by Microsoft for "adding" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type. You can argue about the precise meaning of "extend", but using the official terminology is always the best. There is one false statement in the answer, which I've already corrected in the update section. I have the following question: should I delete the answer? I think modifing the entire answer is not recommended by stackowerflow.

Comment: @toderik Use of the term "extension method" is appropriate.  Saying that it is "extending the type" is not.  While the two seem similar, the first term is correct, the second is not.  The answer starts out with an incorrect statement.  That very first statement is flat wrong, and has not been changed.  Where is there any recommendation that you not correct an incorrect answer?  The site policy is strictly the opposite.  You are *encouraged* to make whatever changes are needed to turn an incorrect answer into a correct one.  That you haven't, despite knowing a mistake, is a *problem*.

Comment: @Servi I understood your point, and I modified the post. But please note that MS itself uses the term "extended type" when talking about extension methods. So I still feel like "extending a type with extended methods" is correct.